# clang-format: Keep trailing specifier on single line

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm looking for a clang-format style option that prevents a list of trailing specifiers to be split and put on separate lines.

Example

```
// Wrong
bool Class::method(bool a, bool b, bool c) const 
    noexcept {
    return a && b && c;
}

// Right
bool Class::method(bool a, bool b,
                   bool c) const noexcept {
    return a && b && c;
}
```

Maybe there is a penalty that can be set for this case, but I couldn't find any. The problem above can even arise when BinPackParameters: false.